# What is phantomjs --wd command alternative for slimerjs?

Tags: phantomjs, phoenix-framework, acceptance-testing, headless-browser, slimerjs

I was using Phantomjs with Phoenix framework for test, and the package I use in phoenix is hound. 
I previously installed phantomjs with apt-get which was giving problems (this [github comment](https://github.com/HashNuke/hound/issues/175#issuecomment-338372928) said the installation method was the culprit), so I downloaded the latest binary from the official website but that was giving `permissions denied` error, so I had to build it from the source, but to my surprise the `build.py` which is mentioned in the official guide wasn't avaialble, so I even failed to build it that way.
I also failed to install through npm, so I gave up on phantomjs.

Now I installed slimerjs, but I don't know what is slimerjs's alternative command to `phantomjs --wd`.

Comment: phantom.js just donwloaded fine for me. I would investigate what yr issue is with that rather than changing tools

Comment: It downloaded for me too, but when I was running it, it was giving permission errors.

Comment: Try different drivers? Maybe one of the ones listed here would help? https://github.com/HashNuke/hound/blob/master/notes/configuring-hound.md